# Servlet to JSP certain element in ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

Im trying pass specific element from my Model to servlet to jsp. 
This is working in my servlet: `System.out.println(beanModel.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1])` When I go to http://localhost:8080/Comparebet/Controller 
But I dont know what Im doing wrong since I dont get it to my jsp. All tutorials ive been watching is mostly input parameters or they put code in the JSP.

**UPDATE EDIT**
Tried with this in my JSP and I get "null"

```
<%= request.getAttribute("rank1") %>
```

**SERVLET**

```
  @WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ArrayList<String> sortedDomainList = new BeanModel().getSortedDomainList();


        BeanModel beanModel = new BeanModel();
        request.setAttribute("rank1", beanModel.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1]);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

        //TESTING SERVLET
        System.out.println(beanModel.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1]);
        System.out.println("CONTROLLER CALLED");
       // System.out.println(${rank1});
    }

     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>CompareBet</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/Controller/*" method="get">

<h1>${rank1.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1] } </h1>

 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your beanmodel class?

Comment: Why do you need to see it? Its working ive tried it in a normal Java application too. And Its working when I print it in the Servlet.

Comment: I wish you could've been more specific than that. Does it print a String?

Comment: Try this `<h1>Testing: ${request.rank1 } </h1>`. Do you see "Testing" printed in JSP? I wonder if you are updating the right JSP.

Comment: @Armaiti Yes I see "Testing:" .

Comment: And yes it prints a string like this "www.qwerty.com" im splitting it because from the begining its "123123;www.qwerty.com"

Comment: @Armaiti `<%= request.getAttribute("rank1") %>` tried with this in my jsp and got "null"

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line in your jsp:

```
 <h1>${rank1.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1] } </h1>
```

To this:

```
  <h1>${rank1} </h1>
```

In JSP you can access this data using the expression language like `${rank1}`.
And take it out from the `<form` like this:

```
    <form action="/Controller/*" method="get"> 
    ...
     </form>
```

Try to use `<h1><%= request.getParameter("rank1")%></h1>`

Comment: @IdontwearString try to check the path of jsp page use ("/view.jsp");

Comment: Where do I check it?

Comment: @IdontwearString try to use the bew path and try

Comment: `RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp");` I changed it to ("/view.jsp") no difference :/

Comment: I dont get what you mean please explain.

Comment: @IdontwearString  take it out from the form  like above

Comment: This is not working either. Is it possible to do some type of test to see if I can pass anything to my jsp?

Comment: Just so I dont miss understand everything I just put "rank1" because its just a name Im right?

Comment: @IdontwearString what happened now?

Comment: Nothing. Im asking you if `request.setAttribute("rank1",` "rank1" is only one a name? or does it actually have to be something?

Comment: @IdontwearString it's just a name you can change it with another if you want?

Comment: No , Its fine I was just thinking that could be the problem.

Comment: `<%= request.getAttribute("rank1") %>` tried with this in my jsp and got "null"

Comment: To know if your request work run this url:     http://localhost:8080/view.jsp?rank1="test".        if you have display test all it's ok

Comment: Not working. Tried http://localhost:8080/Comparebet/view.jsp?rank1=%22test%22 and gets "null"

Comment: @IdontwearString ok i get it try use getParameter like above

Comment: @IdontwearString show me what this print:   System.out.println(beanModel.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1]);

Comment: Ok I think I solved my "problem" when I go to http://localhost:8080/Comparebet/Controller I get what I want. But when not when I go to http://localhost:8080/Comparebet/view.jsp

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP try this, instead of `rank1.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1]`

```
<h1>${request.rank1 } </h1>
```

You have already done `beanModel.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1]` in your servlet and have added the result to the request scope object.

Comment: What does this `System.out.println(beanModel.getSortedDomainList().get(0).split(";")[1]);` print?

Comment: It prints a domain and thats exactly what I want to print to my view/jsp. Its just for testing to console.